# upgrading to apache 2.4 on mediatemple (dv)

Tags: apache, upgrade, apache2.4, mediatemple

I want to upgrade my apache from 2.2 to 2.4 to take advantage of *mod_proxy_wstunnel*.

*mediatemple* support advised that the upgrade may break *plesk*.

I would appreciate hearing from anyone who has experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

Apache 2.4 is officially supported by Plesk 12 at least - http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/parallels-plesk-12.0-for-linux-installation-upgrade-info.html#6
You can update it with usual yum procedure.

Comment: awesome, will take this to the MT folks. thanks IgorG

Comment: plesk 12 requires centos 7.x, and I'm only plesk 11 with centos 6.3. thinking if that were an option they'd have told me up front. or not.

Answer (score 0):

Mediatemple is correct. The upgrade from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4 is supported for [Debian 8 and others](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213944365-After-upgrade-Apache-from-2-2-to-2-4-Apache-is-not-starting), but not by all OS for Plesk. CentOS 6.3, as specified in your comments, will not support it.

Plesk 12 supports Centos 5.1 and 6.x, but [not Apache 2.4](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213917645-Is-it-safe-to-upgrade-Apache-2-4-from-Apache-2-2-on-Plesk-12-5-). I almost broke my VPS by semi-attempting this on CentOS 6.8, mislead by other related articles, before I saw the [fine print](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213917645-Is-it-safe-to-upgrade-Apache-2-4-from-Apache-2-2-on-Plesk-12-5-) on OS support.

> Plesk does not support Apache 2.4 on CentOS 6. Currently, Apache 2.4 is supplied by operating system vendor and is supported by Plesk on CentOS 7, Ubuntu 14, Debian 8. To use Apache 2.4, it is recommended to set up Plesk 12.5 on CentOS 7 and migrate data to it.